# SPE recovery greater than 100%?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, extraction

I am evaluating a paper Gan et. al. 2013 (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.chroma.2012.11.081) Table S4 (see image below) and I am focusing on evaluating the percent recovery for using different solid-phase extraction (SPE) cartridges. Investigators were measuring different artificial sweetener concentrations in water samples. This table suggests that their sucralose (SUC) % recovery was 106% when they used 1 mM TRIS buffer and eluted with methanol and they used a Waters Oasis WAX SPE cartridge. I am assuming n = 3 means they did a sucralose measurement 3 times. **My ultimate question is, how can something have recovery greater than 100% after SPE?** Does the precision and error inflate this recovery value to be over 100?

[image]

Comment: 106% is obviously an experimental error of some sort. Exactly why heaven only knows.

Comment: Exactly as MaxW said. It is important to remember that true values, and experimental estimates of them, are different things. Especially with only three replicate determinations.

Comment: MaxW and Ed V, thank you for your quick feedback. Am I stupid to assume that despite having a 106%, it would mean that they still had an acceptable or adequate % recovery greater than 70%?

Comment: I think it is fine. If it had been 106% with 30 replicates, I would be suspicious: maybe the recovery protocol was not quite correct or whatever. But 30 replicate determinations would be highly atypical: too costly in terms of time, money, materials, etc.

Comment: @EdV Thank you very much again for your feedback and taking the time to answer my questions.